# obecj mysql query has no method by express js

Tags: mysql, node.js

i ve develop a very simple sign up form in express.js but when i redirect and submit the value the express gives me the following error

`500 TypeError: Object # has no method 'query'`

```
at /home/nodes/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/mysql/routes/index.js:79:8
at callbacks (/home/nodes/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/mysql/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
at param (/home/nodes/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/mysql/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
at pass (/home/nodes/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/mysql/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:253:5)
at Router._dispatch (/home/nodes/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/mysql/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:4)
at Object.handle (/home/nodes/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/mysql/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
at next (/home/nodes/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/mysql/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
at /home/nodes/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/mysql/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:322:9
at /home/nodes/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/mysql/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:337:9
at Array.0 (/home/nodes/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/mysql/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory.js:57:7)</code>
```

my code can be viewed from [here](http://www.pastie.org/4102152)

thanx

Answer (score 0):

You should use object `client`, **not** `mysql` when querying.